# UK visitor visa refusal under false documents

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I just got the horrible news that my mom's UK visitor visa has been refused, and it looks like it is accompanied by a possible 10-year ban.

I live in the UK since 2020. I am Tunisian and German and my mom is a Tunisian national. She was to be sponsored by her husband, living with her in Tunisia.

She provided her bank statements showing money that her husband has sent her. She also attached bank statements of her husband proving the transaction and the sufficient funds as well as a letter from him as a sponsor.

The application seemed strong as she provided multiple documents such as: birth certificate of all her kids, their attendance to school in Tunisia, proof of owning a house etc.

In the attached refusal letter, they state that the bank statement was a false document, which is a very serious accusation. It goes without saying that these statements came from her and her husband's bank, with the official stamp.

What caught our attention is the first paragraph outlining the reason. They state : "In support of your application you have provided a statement purportedly issued by BIAT Bank, with an account number ending XXXX, which is in your name and is dated 31/10/23. Checks conducted by this office, contained in a DER and held on file, have concluded to a high degree of certainty that this document is not genuine."

The issue here, is that XXXX is not her number account, but her husband's!!!! So what happened here? Did they mismatch both bank statements (her husband is also at the same bank). It is clear that her bank statements that are under her name have the number account YYYY and not XXXX.

This looks like a real ERROR from the Home Office. Above all this, no way of appeal. Is it also an effective 10-year ban ?

These are serious allegations and could have really bad consequences. Can anyone advise us on what to do?

Thanks a lot for taking the time.

Haifa[image: UK visa refusal]

Comment: I'm sorry for your troubles but this looks like the kind of situation where you need an immigration lawyer. If indeed the UK visa office made an error here one would hope this is fixable but that would require a lawyer well-versed with the UK visa procedures.

Comment: Did your mother clearly indicate in the application that the attached bank statements from her husband were from a sponsor's bank account and not her own account?

Comment: Thank you Quarague. Tor-Einar, the application was accompanied by a letter from her Husband, stating her name and ID, that he will be her sponsor and that he attached to this application his bank statements.

Comment: This definitely a matter to be handled by a qualified immigration attorney in the UK.